# Multiple Autocomplete input not working properly in Laravel

Tags: laravel

SO , i tried a lot to search for a simple manual autocomplete functionality in laravel for input text box and got one wherein script functionality was used . below is the code I wrote :

```
{!! Form::text('search_text', null, array('placeholder' => 'Search...','class' => 'form-control','id'=>'search_text'))!!}
{!! Form::text('customer_auto', null, array('placeholder' => 'Search Customer...','class' => 'form-control','id'=>'customer_auto'))!!}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        src = "{{ route('searchitem') }}";
        $("#search_text").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: src,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        term : request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 3,

        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        src = "{{ route('customersearch') }}";
        $("#customer_auto").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: src,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        term : request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 3,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Either one of the input boxes is only working. 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why you wrote two `$(document).ready` inside each other? It think you should reformat your code to be prettier!

Comment: I have used $(document).ready on after the another, got the solution , please check my answer. thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

src variable was overriding because of which the control was being redirected to only one url which was in the end , changed the code and kept src as one variable and src1 as other which returned the perfect output